# How can I escape the backslash's correctly

Tags: c#, string

I need to escape some Backslashes (`\`) in a string.

I want to execute some command line commands but it has problems with the escape sequences in of it's strings.

This is my Code:

```
using (Process P = new Process())
{
    P.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd";
    P.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    P.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    P.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    P.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    P.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    P.Start();
    P.StandardInput.WriteLine("@echo off");
    string st = "";
    st = @"@for %%a in (\\192.168.85.245\c\ ) do @for /f '\u0022' tokens=3 '\u0022' %%i in ('dir /-c %%a^|find /i '\u0022' Bytes fre '\u0022'') do (set fs_drive=%%a) & (set fs_space=%%i)";
    P.StandardInput.WriteLine(st);
    P.StandardInput.WriteLine("echo Laufwerk %fs_drive%\\ %fs_space% Bytes Frei");
    P.StandardInput.WriteLine("exit");
    P.WaitForExit();
    System.IO.StreamReader sr = P.StandardOutput;
    test = sr.ReadToEnd();
    sr.Close();
}
```

The problem is where the IP.Address is located.
I tried the escaping with the double backslashs (`\\`) and with the "@" in front of the string as seen in the code.

But in both cases the string has the value: `"\\\\192.168.85.245\\c\\"`

When I print the string later it prints it correctly. But when i enter it inside the command line via the WriteLine command the string is not printed correctly.

The desired string is `"\\192.168.85.245\c\"`

Hope you can help me

Comment: When you debug in vs, are you getting the right string in st?

Comment: \\192.168.85.245\c\ I editied my question and added it

Comment: please use this `  character (single quotation) when you want to write backslash in your question

Comment: Why would you expect `\\\\192.168.85.245\c\ ` ? I mean, some slashes to be escaped while other don't

Comment: @ThomasAyoub That was a mistake sorry

Comment: Sorry, you were correct. This is a duplicate and can be closed. I am sorry

Answer (score 1):

`@` is used for string literal:

```
>string st = @"@for %%a in (\\192.168.85.245\c\ ) do @for /f '\u0022' tokens=3 '\u0022' %%i in ('dir /-c %%a^|find /i '\u0022' Bytes fre '\u0022'') do (set fs_drive=%%a) & (set fs_space=%%i)";
>Console.WriteLine(st);
@for %%a in (\\192.168.85.245\c\ ) do @for /f '\u0022' tokens=3 '\u0022' %%i in ('dir /-c %%a^|find /i '\u0022' Bytes fre '\u0022'') do (set fs_drive=%%a) & (set fs_space=%%i)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Your IP is already well formed. When looking at it with the debugger, you'll see it escaped:

[image]